# Python running slow on i7 U processor

Tags: performance, python-3.x, processor

I was using a dell laptop with i7-4810mq(windows 7 pro 64bit version) now I have changed it to i7-5600u with windows 10 pro 64bit.

The problem is that below code was taking at most 2 seconds in my old laptop but now with new processor it takes about 10 minutes and if I am to compare 2 cpus in single core bench i7-4810mq is just 10% faster.

Differences between 2 computers are just processors and operating systems, I cannot see anything that will lead to that much trouble to me. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import pyodbc
import os
import datetime
import math
def setup_Dict(self):
    today = datetime.datetime.today()
    todaystr = today.strftime('%Y.%m.%d')
    DBfile = 'C:/Users/kayd/Desktop/cfgdb/%s/cfg%s.mdb' %(todaystr, todaystr.replace('.', ''))
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ='+DBfile)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    ResultDict={}

    SQL = 'SELECT MxRNC,CELLID,CELLNAME,LOCELL,BANDIND,UARFCNUPLINKIND,UARFCNUPLINK,UARFCNDOWNLINK,CFGRACIND,RAC,CNOPGRPINDEX,MAXTXPOWER,TCELL,NINSYNCIND,NOUTSYNCIND,TRLFAILURE,DLTPCPATTERN01COUNT,PSCRAMBCODE,TXDIVERSITYIND,SPGID,LAC,SAC,CIO,NODEBNAME,VPLIMITIND,DSSFLAG,DSSSMALLCOVMAXTXPOWER,CCHCNOPINDEX,DPGID,CELLHETFLAG FROM UCELLSETUP;'
    for row in cursor.execute(SQL):
        MxRNC=row.MxRNC
        CELLID=row.CELLID
        CELLNAME=row.CELLNAME
        LOCELL=row.LOCELL
        BANDIND=row.BANDIND
        UARFCNUPLINKIND=row.UARFCNUPLINKIND
        UARFCNUPLINK=row.UARFCNUPLINK
        UARFCNDOWNLINK=row.UARFCNDOWNLINK
        CFGRACIND=row.CFGRACIND
        RAC=row.RAC
        CNOPGRPINDEX=row.CNOPGRPINDEX
        MAXTXPOWER=row.MAXTXPOWER
        TCELL=row.TCELL
        NINSYNCIND=row.NINSYNCIND
        NOUTSYNCIND=row.NOUTSYNCIND
        TRLFAILURE=row.TRLFAILURE
        DLTPCPATTERN01COUNT=row.DLTPCPATTERN01COUNT
        PSCRAMBCODE=row.PSCRAMBCODE
        TXDIVERSITYIND=row.TXDIVERSITYIND
        SPGID=row.SPGID
        LAC=row.LAC
        SAC=row.SAC
        CIO=row.CIO
        NODEBNAME=row.NODEBNAME
        CELLHETFLAG=row.CELLHETFLAG
        VPLIMITIND=row.VPLIMITIND
        DSSFLAG=row.DSSFLAG
        DSSSMALLCOVMAXTXPOWER=row.DSSSMALLCOVMAXTXPOWER
        DPGID=row.DPGID
        CCHCNOPINDEX=row.CCHCNOPINDEX

        key = MxRNC + '_' + CELLID
        ResultDict[key] = {'MxRNC':MxRNC,'CELLID':CELLID,'CELLNAME':CELLNAME,'LOCELL':LOCELL,'BANDIND':BANDIND,'UARFCNUPLINKIND':UARFCNUPLINKIND,'UARFCNUPLINK':UARFCNUPLINK,'UARFCNDOWNLINK':UARFCNDOWNLINK,'CFGRACIND':CFGRACIND,'RAC':RAC,'CNOPGRPINDEX':CNOPGRPINDEX,'MAXTXPOWER':MAXTXPOWER,'TCELL':TCELL,'NINSYNCIND':NINSYNCIND,'NOUTSYNCIND':NOUTSYNCIND,'TRLFAILURE':TRLFAILURE,'DLTPCPATTERN01COUNT':DLTPCPATTERN01COUNT,'PSCRAMBCODE':PSCRAMBCODE,'TXDIVERSITYIND':TXDIVERSITYIND,'SPGID':SPGID,'LAC':LAC,'SAC':SAC,'CIO':CIO,'NODEBNAME':NODEBNAME,'CELLHETFLAG':CELLHETFLAG,'VPLIMITIND':VPLIMITIND,'DSSFLAG':DSSFLAG,'DSSSMALLCOVMAXTXPOWER':DSSSMALLCOVMAXTXPOWER,'DPGID':DPGID,'CCHCNOPINDEX':CCHCNOPINDEX}
```

Comment: Is the database exactly the same? The query is unbounded so a much larger database will take longer to process.

Comment: I'd expect that this problem would be I/O bound. What storage are you using in both bases? Are database files are exactly the same? If bigger DB is used in second case, obviously it would take much more time to process.

Comment: Database is the same database I have used before so nothing is changed and in terms of storage I have a better ssd now.